# Python Pandas: After converting dataframe to Str NAN is no more NAN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe imported from Excel. After importing I have checked there are lots of **NAN** values in the dataframe. When I convert dataframe columns to Str Object. There are no NAN values remains. My mean is that dataframe can't be able to count NAN values anymore. Those **NAN** values showed as **nan** in the dataframe. I actually wants those **NAN** to be empty cells in the dataframe like Excel. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at .fillna()

You can use that to edit the NaNs before converting the column values to strings.